# closed formula for the function

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, polynomials, proof-explanation

Suppose function $f$ is such that for any $x\in R_+$ we have that
$$
f(\, x(x-1)\ldots(x-k+1)\, )=A_k.
$$
Moreover,  the following holds for all $k$:
$$
f(x)=A_1\\
f(x(x-1))=f(x^2-x)=f(x^2)-f(x)=A_2\\
f(x(x-1)(x-2))=f(x^3-3x^2+2x)=x^3-3f(x^2)+2f(x)=A_3\\
\ldots
$$
**Question:** I would like to find a closed formula, or at least an upper bound of $f(x^n)$ in terms of $A_i$.

**My attempt:**
I have started representing $f(x^n)$ as following, but I cannot find a pattern:
$$
f(x)=A_1\\
f(x^2)=A_2+f(x)=A_2+A_1\\
f(x^3)=A_3-3f(x^2)-2f(x)=A_3+3A_2+3A_1-2A_1=A_3+3A_2+A_1\\
\ldots
$$

Comment: If $\prod_i f(y_i) = f(\prod_i y_i)$ then you have just
$f(x^n) = (f(x))^n = {A_1}^n$ or am I misunderstanding your statement?

Comment: Yes, I have probably correct it. I meant that you can pool out multiplayer, i.e. $f(3x)=3f(x)$

Comment: I don't understand the way you're using the notation of functions here. Suppose $x=2$, and note that $2=2(2-1)=x(x-1)$. So do we have $f(2)=f(x)=A_1$, or do we have $f(2)=f(x(x-1))=A_2$?

Comment: @Barry Cipra: We assuming that $f(x)=A_1$. In the case you have provided it  happened that $f(x(x-1))=A_2=A_1=f(x)$, which is partial case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that finite product is $$x(x-1)\cdots (x-k+1)=\sum_{m=0}^k S_k^m x^m,$$ which is basically a list of Stirling numbers of the first kind, you are essentially trying to invert that matrix of the Stirling numbers of the first kind and get the Stirling numbers of the second kind, with coefficients listed e.g. in https://oeis.org/A008277.

Comment: Yes, I figured that out by trying all the different powers. But how that inversion of the matrix would work? Can you please elaborate on your answer? Thank you

Comment: The inversion is clearly stated as $$x^n=\sum_{m=0}^n \frac S_n^{(m)} x(x-1)\cdots (x-m+1)$$ in Section 24.1.4 of the book by Abramowitz and Stegun, for example, where $\frac S_n^{(m)}$ are the Stirling numbers of the second kind.